# It is not running statements at one time. like the runtime in sololearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have downloded python 3.8 and idle want to execute the full code at single time. I also tried copying and then pasting and executing then it is saying syntax error "found multiple statements when trying to execute single statement".

Comment: Can you please copy paste your code here?

Comment: x=input()
y=input()
print(x+y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are trying to execute in the console with multiple lines, please run in terminal after saving the file. Locate your terminal in python file path and give python  in terminal

Comment: thanks! can you tell me how do i run it in terminal, because i am new to python

Comment: Yeah, sure. Copy paste your code in text file and save it as vinayak.py in desktop. Then, go to terminal navigate to desktop directory, finally run the program by python vinayak.py

Comment: Can you please accept my answer by pressing tick  and up arrow on my answer?

Comment: yeah sure! but can you tell me where is the tick

Comment: On the left hand side below the answer, please press up arrow and tick

Comment: My number is 8778479731 if you any input from me I can ready to give, because, I'm python developer